# How to print only the filename part of files that contain a certain string?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, find

I need to print out the filename (e.g. `A001.txt`) that contains the string "XYZ".
I tried this:
`grep -H -R "XYZ" ~/directory/*.txt | cut -d':' -f1`

It would output the entire path (e.g. `~/directory/A001.txt`). How can I make it so that it would only output the filename (e.g. `A001.txt`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -lr term dir/to/search/ | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'` should do the trick.

`-l` just lists filenames, including their directories.

`-r` is recursive to go through the directory tree and all files in the dir specified.

This all gets piped to `awk`, which is told to use `/` as a delimiter (not allowed in file names, so not as brittle as it could be) and to print the last field (`NF` is the field count, so `$NF` is the last field)

Answer (score 3):

Why oh why did the GNU guys give grep an option to recursively find files when there's a perfectly good tool designed for the job and with an extremely obvious name. Sigh...

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/XYZ/{print gensub(/.*\//,"",1,FILENAME); nextfile}' {} +
```

The above uses GNU awk which I assume you have since you were planning to use GNU grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Rl "content" | xargs -d '\n' basename -a
```

This should do the trick and print only the filename without the path.

> **basename** prints filename NAME with any leading directory components
> removed.
>
> *Reference:* https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename

Comment: and if you have GNU utils for `-d '\n'` then you should go all the way and use grep -Z and xargs -0.